Story where people spend their retirement immersed in a virtual world
I read this short story or novella in the 90s, I think it was part of an anthology.
It features a retirement home where the residents have their brains wired, Matrix-style, into an elaborate virtual environment. The connection is reversible, but residents normally stay connected until they die.
While connected, their catatonic bodies are looked after by the staff. The care and lack of stress extends their life, so they normally get 30 to 40 years in their virtual paradise.
A woman goes to visit her mother, and is temporarily connected to the virtual environment so she can talk to her.  She finds her mother, who is playing the part of a fairy in a fantasy setting. The daughter is unsettled to realise that her mother doesn't remember her and believes her new world is real.
Some changes are made, I think at the daughter's suggestion, and she goes back later to see her mother again.  This time, the mother recognises her and they converse. The mother now has a fulfilling office job, doing work for a real-world company in a virtual office, and stepping out each evening into an idealised holiday location. She comments that she and her fellow residents do so much work that she wonders how the real world used to survive without them.

Great... "retirement" is now just virtual work. Sounds like a horror story to me! ;)

Check out the works of author Peter Watts; he described the same type of virtual retirement in his novel "Blindsight" (2006), and may have used it in other stories.

I can't name the story, but does the phrase Golden Life ring a bell?

@AntonSherwood No, but it's been a long time. I do think the company in the story had an appropriately retirement-home-like name, so it might have been Golden Life.

@FreeMan, have you seen Dark Mirror episode “White Christmas”?

Haven't seen any of Dark Mirror, @AntonSherwood. IMDB doesn't seem to know of a TV show by that name, but horror isn't my genre, anyway...

@FreeMan Would you believe Black Mirror?  Not the first time I've made that mistake or the reciprocal.
